# UITapGestureRecognizer Point Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, cgpoint

I'm trying to implement a tap gesture recognizer into my app.
Ideally I need for the tap gesture to return the `x` and `y` coordinates, so I can then create a variable to apply to a core image filter using a parameter which requires the `x` and `y` values. e.g, the user taps their nose, the gesture recognizer passes the coordinates(a variable, say, `nosePosition.x` and `nosePosition.y`) into a filter such as `CIBumpDistorion`, which need the `x` and `y` values for its `kCIInputCenterKey`.

I have tried using quite a few methods and moving/deleting code all to no avail. So if anyone has some advice I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 10):

Would that work ?

```
func touch(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = sender.locationInView(self.view)
    let x = point.x
    let y = point.y
}
```

Comment: Hi La masse, Thanks for your reply. I'll give it a try later, hopefully it'll work!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One change is that sender.locationInView(self.view) has changed to sender.location(in: self.view)